# missing assembly reference

Tags: asp.net

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ShoppingCart' does not exist in the namespace 'MyWebsite.Commerce' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase {

    public virtual MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart Cart {
        get {
            return ((MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart)(this.GetPropertyValue("Cart")));
        }
        set {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Cart", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string Country {
        get {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Country")));
        }
        set {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Country", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual string Gender {
        get {
            return ((string)(this.GetPropertyValue("Gender")));
        }
        set {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Gender", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual int Age {
        get {
            return ((int)(this.GetPropertyValue("Age")));
        }
        set {
            this.SetPropertyValue("Age", value);
        }
    }

    public virtual ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username) {
        return ((ProfileCommon)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
    }
}
```

when i run  this page the an error occured and when i clicked the error line it goes to above code please anyone help me ASAP please.......

Comment: Where is your shopping cart class? I suspect it's not where you think it is or you haven't added a reference to it.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear: `ShoppingCart does not exist in the namespace MyWebsite.Commerce`. Where is `ShoppingCart` class declared? If it is not in the same assembly did you reference this assembly?

Comment: READ the Error message!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your project references - most likely the one that points to the assembly that contains `MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart` is missing.  Is this a project reference?  Perhaps you simply haven't built the solution yet.