# missing assembly reference

Tags: asp.net

Duplicate : [missing assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714587/missing-assembly-reference)

hi everyone
please help me

my Shopping.cs file is given below

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MyWebsite.Commerce;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace MyWebsite.Commerce
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CartItem
    {
        private int _productID;
        private string _productName;
        private string _productURL;
        private int _quantity;
        private double _price;
        private double _lineTotal;
        public void New()
        {
        }
        public void New(int ProductID, string ProductName, string ProductURL, int Quantity, double Price)
        {
            _productID = ProductID;
            _productName = ProductName;
            _productURL = ProductURL;
            _quantity = Quantity;
            _price = Price;
            _lineTotal = Quantity * Price;
        }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductURL { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double LineTotal { get; set; }


        [Serializable]

        public class ShoppingCart
        {
            private DateTime _dateCreated;
            private DateTime _lastUpdate;
            private List<CartItem> _items;
            public ShoppingCart()
            {
                if (this._items = null)
                {
                    this._items = new List<CartItem>();
                    this._dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            public List<CartItem> Items
            { get; set; }
            public void Insert(int ProductID, string ProductName, string ProductURL, int Quantity, double Price)
            {
                int ItemIndex = ItemIndexOfID(ProductID);
                if (ItemIndex == -1)
                {
                    CartItem NewItem = new CartItem();
                    NewItem.ProductID = ProductID;
                    NewItem.ProductName = ProductName;
                    NewItem.ProductURL = ProductURL;
                    NewItem.Price = Price;
                    NewItem.Quantity = Quantity;
                    _items.Add(NewItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    _items[ItemIndex].Quantity += 1;
                }
                _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }

            public void Update(int RowID, int ProductID, int Quantity, double Price)
            {
                CartItem Item = _items[RowID];
                Item.ProductID = ProductID;
                Item.Quantity = Quantity;
                Item.Price = Price;
                _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            public void DeleteItem(int rowID)
            {
                _items.RemoveAt(rowID);
                _lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            private int ItemIndexOfID(int ProductID)
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (CartItem item in _items)
                {
                    if (item.ProductID == ProductID)
                    {
                        return index;
                    }
                    index += 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            public double Total
            {
                get
                {
                    double t = 0;
                    if (_items == null)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    foreach (CartItem Item in _items)
                    {
                        t += Item.LineTotal;
                    }
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

and then i create a web user control file ShoppingCart.ascx and ShoppingCart.ascx.cs file code are given below of ShoppingCart.ascx.cs

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using MyWebsite.Commerce;


public partial class ShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Profile.Cart == null)
        {
            Profile.Cart = new MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart();
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
        if (Profile.Cart.Items == null)
        {
            TotalLabel.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    protected void CartGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        CartGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void CartGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox QuantityTextBox = (TextBox)CartGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
        int Quantity = Convert.ToString(QuantityTextBox.Text);
        if (Quantity == 0)
        {
            Profile.Cart.Items.RemoveAt(e.RowIndaex);
        }
        else
        {
            Profile.Cart.Items[e.RowIndex].Quantity = Quantity;
        }
        CartGrid.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void CartGrid_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        CartGrid.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
    protected void CartGrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Profile.Cart.Items.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        CartGrid.DataSource = Profile.Cart.Items;
        DataBind();
        TotalLabel.Text = string.Format("Total : {0,19:c}", Profile.Cart.Total);
    }
}
```

when i drag and drop ShoppingCart.ascx file on to ShoppingCartPage.aspx file and run the application the there is a error occurred,when i clicked the error the i go on to this below code

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The
>   type or namespace name 'ShoppingCart'
>   does not exist in the namespace
>   'MyWebsite.Commerce' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)
>
> Line 17: public class ProfileCommon :
>   System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase { Line
>   18:      Line 19:     public virtual
>   MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart Cart {
>   Line 20:         get { Line 21:
>   return
>   ((MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart)(this.GetPropertyValue("Cart")));

please help me..................

Comment: you posted the same question yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it's the best or only way to go about troubleshooting this, but I'd try deleting all references and adding them one by one til you get things working again..

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty difficult to grasp for me so i'm just going to throw an idea in here for you to test. as i see your class

you have

```
namespace MyWebsite.Commerce
```

and then in that you have a class CartItem. Then instead of having another completely seperate class ShoppingCart, you have that class inside CartItem.

i could be wrong (since i haven't tried testing this) but i think the line in your ascx

```
Profile.Cart = new MyWebsite.Commerce.ShoppingCart();
```

should be

```
Profile.Cart = new MyWebsite.Commerce.CartItem.ShoppingCart();
```

note the additional CartItem.

alternatively write the ShoppingCart class as a separate class within the MyWebsite.Commerce namespace.